# Перебор массива, и вставка каждые Nx3 определенного элемента

Tags: php, массивы

есть массив:

```
$marks = array('Audi', 'BMW', 'Volkswagen', 'Mersedes', 'Porshe', 'Volvo', 'Land Rover', 'Bentley');
foreach($marks as $key  => $mark){
    echo $mark;
};
```

нужно вывести элементы не просто один за другим, а в блоках по 3.

подскажите как написать это условие?

чтобы на выходе получилось вот так

```
<div class="row">Audi BMW Volkswagen</div>
<div class="row">Mersedes Porshe Volvo</div>
<div class="row">LandRover Bentley</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно разбить массив на части с помощью `array_chunk()`, пройтись по полученному массиву циклом, в теле которого объединить необходимые массивы в строку, с подстановкой html-тегов:

```
$marks = array('Audi','BMW','Volkswagen','Mersedes','Porshe','Volvo','Land Rover','Bentley');

foreach (array_chunk($marks, 3) as $mark) {
    echo '<div class="row">' . join(' ', $mark) . '</div>';
};
```

---

**UPD:**

---

Если задача - разбить именно по условию, то можно так *(но в ущерб компактности кода)*:

```
echo '<div class="row">';

foreach ($marks as $k => $mark) {
    echo !(++$k % 3) ? $mark . '</div><div class="row">' : $mark .' ';
};

echo  '</div>';
```

Можно вместо цикла взять подходящую функцию, и записать в одну строку *(но в ущерб читабельности)*:

```
array_map(function($a){ echo '<div class="row">'. join(' ', $a) .'</div>'; }, array_chunk($marks, 3));
```